# Dockerfile: `curl` command unable to save file

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile

I'm building what I think is a simple `dockerfile` and have got one line in the code that is throwing an error.

```
# dockerfile
...
RUN     curl -k --output bin/theta `curl -k 'https://mainnet-data.thetatoken.org/binary?os=linux&name=theta'`
RUN     curl -k --output bin/thetacli `curl -k 'https://mainnet-data.thetatoken.org/binary?os=linux&name=thetacli'`
RUN     curl -k --output guardian_mainnet/node/config.yaml `curl -k 'https://mainnet-data.thetatoken.org/config?is_guardian=true'`
...
```

The first two curl commands run without any issue.  The third curl command throws an error:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file guardian_mainnet/node/config.yaml: No such file or directory
```

The directory is created and does exist.  The prior two `curl` commands use exactly the same format and result in both the `theta` and `thetacli` files being created.

I've actually setup a docker container with the base image predicated on the `FROM` for this dockerfile.  From there I've run the code in the `dockerfile` line-by-line and it has executed without any problem (including the third line).  In other words, if I manually run the dockerfile commands from the CLI for the base container it works - it's only when building the container from the dockerfile at the host level that the error is thrown.

The only differences are (i) the file type of `.yaml` and (ii) the `?` in the https link.  But I've found nothing that says that would be a problem. [I've tried saving without the extension and it didn't make a difference.]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you `RUN ls -ld guardian_mainnet/node` immediately before this line (or otherwise check in the partially built image); does the directory actually exist, in the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze - good catch and it highlighted the problem.  When `mkdir` earlier it is in a different working directory, so my `mkdir` gets created just not where I thought it was.  I went through and use absolute paths and got it to work.  The first two lines were in the same working directory and that's why they didn't throw an error.

Comment: What's also clear is that managing directory location when in `cli` is different managing directory location when executing in dockerfile build (even as `root`).

Answer (score 0):

Please add `--create-dirs` to create necessary dirs when saving with `--output`. And pay attention to your user and group while doing this.

> --create-dirs
> When  used in conjunction with the -o, --output option, curl will create the necessary local directory hierarchy as needed. This option creates the dirs mentioned with the -o, --output option, nothing else. If the --output file name uses no dir or if the dirs it mentions already exist, no dir will be created.
>
> To create remote directories when using FTP or SFTP, try --ftp-create-dirs.